# Hide some characters from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In my JavaScript app, user will insert his info in a form. I would like to hide each '-' or '.' or '/' he  possibly would type before processing his information. Is there any JavaScript function to do that?
In my case, the string could contain any of these characters, all or none. So I think I cannot use replace function. What do you think?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Why don't you try extracting characters from a string, and saving it as a new string?

Comment: You could use the `.replace()` function with a regular expression to match all occurrences of any of those characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onkeyup` event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableSomeChars(event) {
    if (!event) {
        event = window.event;
    }
    if (
        event.keyCode === 191 // "/"
        event.keyCode === 189 // "-"
    ) {
        event.preventDefault(); // cancel the event
    }
}
</script>

<input type="text" onkeyup="disableSomeChars()" />
```

Keep in mind that this does not yet block copy-pasting of text. To fix that you could add a function `onchange` that will cleanup the text field, using `.replace(/[\/-]/g, "");` (remove `/` and `-`).

Answer (score 0):

You can catch them on keydown.

So when the user presses those keys when in the input pox, you can parse them out.